# .intersects always returning true?

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I've been working on a game with a mix of awt and slick2d (Rendering is done via awt). Anyway, i'm having a problem with collision. Inside of entity class, I have a collision method:

```
public boolean colidesWithWall(int idx, int idy) {
    //if(Level.solid)
    wall = new Rectangle(idx, idy, Tile.Size, Tile.Size);
    if (this.getBoundingBox() == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return this.getBoundingBox().intersects(wall);


}
```

Outside of this in my "Core.java" file, I have a for loop iterate the tiles through the colidesWithWall method. I also have an if statement in here so it will only check the tiles that are on the collision layer. (My map has four layers, Background, Collision, Items and Enemies).

```
for (int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++) {
            Entity me = entities.get(i);

            for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < 100; l++) {
                    if (Level.getColision(k, l)) {
                        Entity entity = entities.get(i);
                        if (entity.colidesWithWall(k, l)) {
                            entity.collidedWithWall();
                            frameCounter = 0;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Well anyway, what happens is, the game always detects a collision going on. Also, the players X&Y coordinates are defined by this:

```
 ((int) ((rouge.screenSize.width) / 2 - Tile.Size / 2 + rouge.oX)) / Tile.Size, ((int((rouge.screenSize.height) / 2 - Tile.Size / 2 + rouge.oY))/Tile.size
```

rouge.oY and rouge.oX are my camera offsets

Tile.Size is the size of my Tiles: 32

Here's a Screenshot of what happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY6S7.png

The grey tiles and the tree are supposed to be causing collision, where as the brown ones are not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have for my game. I hope it somehow helps you as I'm not sure how I can help with just what you've given.

Getting the player's bounds:

```
private static Rectangle getPlayerBounds() {
    return new Rectangle((int)player.getPositionX(), (int)player.getPositionY(), playerTexture.getImageWidth(), playerTexture.getImageHeight());
}
```

Getting the entity(in my case enemy)'s bounds:

```
private static Rectangle getEnemyBounds(Enemy e) {
    return new Rectangle(e.getEnemyPosX(), e.getEnemyPosY(), enemyTexture.getImageWidth(), enemyTexture.getImageHeight());
}
```

then I have my checkCollision():

```
public static void checkCollisions() {
     for(int i = 0; i < getEnemyList().size(); i++) {

        Enemy tempEnemy = getEnemyList().get(i);

        if (getPlayerBounds().intersects(getEnemyBounds(tempEnemy))) {
            getEnemyList().remove(tempEnemy);
        }
    }
}
```

and in the end I just call it in my Movement.java:

```
    MovementChecks.checkCollisions();
```

Comment: Not related to the question, but why do you use repetitive words in functions like `getEnemyPosX()`, when you have a class named `Enemy`. Wouldnt it be easier to read `e.getPosX()`

Comment: It's a leftover name from it being in another class initially.